# cannot get python pandas google analytics connection to work

Tags: python, pandas, google-analytics, google-api

I am trying to run this very basic code (found at http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/remote_data.html#remote-data-ga):

```
import pandas.io.ga as ga
    ga.read_ga(
        account_id  = "ZZZZZZZZZZ",
        profile_id  = "YYYYYYYYYY",
        property_id = "XXXXXXXXX",
        metrics     = ['users', 'pageviews'],
        dimensions  = ['dayOfWeek'],
        start_date  = "2014-01-01",
        end_date    = "2014-08-01")
```

I get the following result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled.py", line 14, in <module>
    end_date    = "2015-01-01"

File "C:\Users\gwaldman\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\sitepackages\pandas\io\ga.py", line 105, in read_gareader = GAnalytics(**reader_kwds)

File "C:\Users\gwaldman\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\sitepackages\pandas\io\ga.py", line 174, in __init__self._service = self._init_service(secrets)
File "C:\Users\gwaldman\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\sitepackages\pandas\io\ga.py", line 186, in _init_servicehttp = self.authenticate(secrets)
File "C:\Users\gwaldman\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\sitepackages\pandas\io\ga.py", line 146, in authenticate return auth.authenticate(flow, self.token_store)
File "C:\Users\gwaldman\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda\lib\sitepackages\pandas\io\auth.py", line 108, in authenticate credentials = tools.run(flow, storage)

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'
```

I followed the instructions for authenticating with Google APIs, and have been able to do it successfully, but can't seem to get it to work with pandas. I downloaded a client_secrets file and put it in the same folder as pandas.io.ga

I am also running Anaconda Python. Have searched and tried tons of stuff, but cannot seem to even get to authentication.

Comment: Are you running this code in iPython or from Terminal?

Comment: pandas is using a deprecated method (https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/1d8717446d8666207b63ae324e56be60a0b01b07/pandas/io/auth.py#L108), which was removed from the underlying library Aug 25th https://github.com/google/oauth2client/commit/05ae3426f271515bab4dc6a210428300286438e8 

You should file an issue with pandas git repo or you could submit a pull request yourself to use the correct method.

Answer (score 1):

As @[Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3791516/matt) has suggested, either file a ticket with the owners of Pandas to change (currently) line 108 of [pandas/io/auth.py](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/1d8717446d8666207b63ae324e56be60a0b01b07/pandas/io/auth.py) from `run()` to `run_flow()`, or make the fix yourself and file a PR.

For other developers running into this error: If you have the latest version ([as of Feb 2016](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/1d8717446d8666207b63ae324e56be60a0b01b07/pandas/io/auth.py)) of the [Google APIs Client Library for Python](https://github.com/google/oauth2client/commit/98df500a29157ccaa3f6bdf4517d57a5be8e85f1), just **rename** your call from `tools.run()` to `tools.run_flow()`, and you should be good-to-go. More about this change in a PSA (public service announcement) [blogpost](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python) I wrote back in mid-2015 but update periodically to current.

The fastest way to upgrade your Client Library is with:
`pip install -U google-api-python-client  # or pip3 for 3.x`